# Visual Studio 2017 RC Core Console Project does not compile

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I create a new enoty core console project  it doesn't compile

I can see that the nuget packages are not restored.

[image]

when i run `dotnet restore` i get the error

> microsoft.net.sdk\1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2\build\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(45,5):
>   error : RuntimeIdentifier must be set for .NETFramework executables.
>   Consider RuntimeIdentifier=win7-x86 or RuntimeIdentifier=win7-x64.

what am i missing?

Comment: Try editing you csproj and add `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64;win7-x86;osx.10.10-x64;osx.10.11-x64;ubuntu.14.04-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64;centos.7-x64;rhel.7.2-x64;debian.8-x64;fedora.23-x64;opensuse.13.2-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` inside your `<PropertyGroup>` element

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by @annemartijn, but then without the s

`<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeI‌​dentifier>`

See issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4619

Insert the runtime identifier segment in your .csproj file:

```
<Project...
  <Import...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    ...
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeI‌​dentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```